# Insertar nueva fila para modificar un registro de una tabla mysql (PHP/HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Primero agradecer a quien me pueda ayudar sobre este tema, que he tratado de resolver por mi cuenta pero no logro dar con la clave. Lo que necesito es actualizar registros de una tabla concreta de una base de datos. He precargado en un *select* la *key* (registro único) y al hacer click debería crearse una nueva linea con los datos del registro en unos *inputs*, para después modificar los campos que el usuario desee. El problema es que no se como hacerlo, solo he logrado cargar la *key*, pero me es imposible cargar el resto de datos. El código:

HTML

```
<select name="selectModificar" id="selectorModificar" onclick="recogerValor()">
<option value="0" selected disabled>...</option>
<?php
    $consulta = "Select * from prueba.S";
    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $datos['Cod_prov'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['Cod_prov'] ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

JS

```
var miTabla = document.querySelector("table");

function recogerValor() {
var select = document.getElementById('selectorModificar');
var selectedOption = '';
select.addEventListener('change',
    function () {
        selectedOption = this.options[select.selectedIndex];
        modificar_seleccion(selectedOption);
    });
}

function modificar_seleccion(selectedOption) {
    var row = miTabla.insertRow(miTabla.rows.length);
    var celda1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var celda2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var celda3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var celda4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var celda5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var celda6 = row.insertCell(5);
    celda1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="Cod_prov" value="' + selectedOption.value + '"' + 'readonly style="background-color: grey; border: 1px solid blue;">';
    celda2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="Nombre" required>';
    celda3.innerHTML = '<input type="number" name="edad" min="0" max="100" required>';
    celda4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="ciudad" required>';
    celda5.innerHTML = '<input type="number" name="status" min="0" max="100" required>';
    celda6.innerHTML = '<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Modificar Registro" style="padding: 5px;"></input>';
}
```

PHP

```
    function mostrar_datos($conexion)
{
    $consulta = "Select * from prueba.S order by lpad(Cod_prov, 10, 0)";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    if ($resultado) {
    echo '<form action="procesar.php" method="POST" id="myForm">';
    echo "<table class='tabla'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    //mostrar cabecera tabla
    $campos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SHOW FIELDS from prueba.S");
    while ($v = mysqli_fetch_row($campos)) {
        echo "<td><b>" . $v[0] . "</b></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    //mostrar las filas de la tabla
    while ($v = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($v as $valor) {
            echo "<td>" .  $valor . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
    mysqli_free_result($resultado); //Liberar la memoria
} else {
    echo '<script>alert ("¡Error de conexión! Contacte con su administrador.");window.location="index.php";</script>';
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y una vez seleccionado el proveedor, deberían cargarse todos los datos del registro en los inputs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código relacionado con `mitabla` tambien? tanto el html como el javascript, gracias

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende. *El problema es que no se como hacerlo, solo he logrado cargar la key, pero me es imposible cargar el resto de datos.* ¿A qué te refieres exactamente (indica la parte exacta del código donde tienes el problema). Di también qué depuraciones has hecho al respecto. Deberías depurar con `var_dump` (PHP)  o con `console.log` (Javascript) aquellas variables u objetos problemáticos. ¿Lo has hecho? ¿Con qué resultados?

Comment: La idea es cargar en una nueva linea todos los datos del registro seleccionado en el select, en el ejemplo la primary Key S3131 seleccionada al hacer click debería cargarse también el nombre, edad, provincia, estado, es decir, Maria, 20, Malaga, 10, y por el momento solo he logrado insertar el código S3131. Creo que la clave está en hacer llegar los datos desde PHP al JS, a la funcion modificar_seleccion(), y ahí hacer un innerHTML a cada celda/input, pero, ¿como llevo los datos hasta ahí? Hice un console.log y me devuelve siempre la key(codigo).

Comment: Vamos avanzando, pero a paso de tortuga, aun asi me he animado a intentar ayudarte. De momento veo esto: 1) Quita el `onclick="recogerValor()"` (ya estas supervisando esa accion en el js). 2) Quita el `function recogerValor() {` y tambien su cierre más abajo `}`. Con eso conseguiras que no repita la accion varias veces y no te inserte varias lineas a la vez.  Y a partir de ahi siguen faltando datos para seguir ayudandote. Miralo tu mismo en este ejemplo que he hecho con lo que nos has dado hasta ahora: https://jsfiddle.net/zkpm0auf/

Comment: Bueno, creo que ya lo voy entendiendo mejor. Te faltan basicamente dos cosas para empezar: 1) una función o un archivo en php que recoja el dato clave y lo consulte en la base de datos (de momento solo muestras toda la tabla, pero debes tener una función que solo devuelva uno basado en su clave).  y 2) Dentro de `modificar_seleccion` debes realizar una llamada ajax a esa función o archivo PHP pasandole la clave y luego gestionar su retorno. Para ello mira [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/504903/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-una-respuesta-json-en-mi-formulario/504916#504916) a ver si te ayuda

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias. Le voy a dar un par de vueltas a eso a ver si soy capaz de hacerlo funcionar. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

De pronto te podria sugerir otra manera de hacerlo, yo tengo un codigo parecido de un proyecto en el que trabaje, podrias poner un boton de editar al lado de cada registro para que tome el id

Para el boton de editar puedes ponerlo asi

```
<a href="editar-registro.php?id=<?php echo $datos ["Cod_prov"]; ?>"><input type="button" value="Editar"></a>

    <?php 
        $id= $_GET ["id"];
        $consulta="SELECT * from prueba WHERE Cod_prov='$id'";
        $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){   
                    
    ?>
    <div>
       <td><?php echo $datos['Cod_prov']?></td>
       <td><?php echo $datos['nombre']?></td>
       <td><?php echo $datos['edad']?></td>
       <td><?php echo $datos['ciudad']?></td>
       <td><?php echo $datos['estatus']?></td>
       
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo tengo solucionado. Lo que hice fue pasar como *value* todos los valores del registro separados por **espacios**, en vez de enviar solo el *Cod_prov*:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y desde JS hice un *split()* formando un nuevo array con los datos, y los asignané a cada una de las *celdas/inputs* correspondiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y se hizo la luz...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML y PHP:

```
                <select name="selectModificar" id="selectorModificar" onclick="recogerValor()">
                    <option value="0" selected disabled>...</option>
                    <?php
                    $consulta = "Select * from prueba.S";
                    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
                    while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $datos['Cod_prov'] . ',' . $datos['Nombre'] . ',' . $datos['edad'] . ',' . $datos['ciudad'] . ',' . $datos['status'] ?>">
                            <?php echo $datos['Cod_prov'] ?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

JS

```
function modificar_seleccion(selectedOption) {
var array_selectedOption = selectedOption.value.split(',');
//console.log(array_selectedOption);
ocultarCampos();
var row = miTabla.insertRow(miTabla.rows.length);
var celda1 = row.insertCell(0);
var celda2 = row.insertCell(1);
var celda3 = row.insertCell(2);
var celda4 = row.insertCell(3);
var celda5 = row.insertCell(4);
var celda6 = row.insertCell(5);
celda1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="Cod_prov" value="' + array_selectedOption[0] + '"' + 'readonly style="background-color: grey; border: 1px solid blue;">';
celda2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="Nombre" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{2,254}" value="' + array_selectedOption[1] + '"' + 'required>';
celda3.innerHTML = '<input type="number" name="edad" min="0" max="100" value="' + array_selectedOption[2] + '"' + 'required>';
celda4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="ciudad" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{2,254}" value="' + array_selectedOption[3] + '"' + 'required>';
celda5.innerHTML = '<input type="number" name="status" value="' + array_selectedOption[4] + '"' + 'min="0" max="100" required>';
celda6.innerHTML = '<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Modificar Registro" style="padding: 5px;"></input>';
}
```

Comment: Con esta solución no se si nadie que se llame "Juan Antonio" o viva en "A Coruña" saldrá correctamente en tu resultado

Comment: En ese caso lo voy a separar por comas (,) así no habrá fallo en nombres o ciudades compuestas separadas por un espacio.

Comment: Saludos, Peter, sería bueno si podrías dejar la respuesta del código en texto en caso de que alguien más lo necesite.